# How to change a copy of a component's state without changing the component's state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Should changing the copy of the component's state change the state? ->

```
function component(props) {
    const [state, set_state] = useState([a, b, c]);

    const handleClick = () => {
        var state_copy = [...state];
        state_copy[2] = d;
        runSimulationWithState(state_copy);
    }

    return (
        {state.map((item) => {
            <li>{ item }</li>
        }
        <button onClick={() => {handleClick} ></button>
    );
}
```

I had situation where I had to check how future states of my component could look like and every time I changed the copy of the component's state the state would change also. The only way around this that I found was to redo the change I made to the copy of the state like so ->

```
var state_copy = [...state];
var item = state_copy[2]
state_copy[2] = d;
runSimulationWithState(state_copy);
state_copy[2] = item;
```

State looked somthing like this ->

```
const state = [['bR', 'bKn', 'bB', 'bQ', 'bK', 'bB', 'bKn', 'bR'],
    ['bP', 'bP', 'bP', 'bP', 'bP', 'bP', 'bP', 'bP'],
    ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
    ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
    ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
    ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
    ['wP', 'wP', 'wP', 'wP', 'wP', 'wP', 'wP', 'wP'],
    ['wR', 'wKn', 'wB', 'wQ', 'wK', 'wB', 'wKn', 'wR']];
```

I thought that state could only be changed with set_state function that you declare. Has anyone encountered this? Am I not understanding something about React or Javascript itself?

Comment: Welcome to SO! In React hooks, there is only one way to change state: `setState` (or as you call it, `set_state`). All state is effectively immutable. Although you haven't shown `runSimulationWithState`, It's not sensible to reason about what React might do when you break the rules of immutability--it might work, it might not, but you're getting involved with implementation-specific, off-limits internal logic that diffs data structures and determines when/what to rerender. React can only guarantee the behavior will be normal when you follow its contract.

Comment: I don't think OP is trying to change the state, what they want to do is make a local, slightly modified copy of state to do something with it on the side. However, when creating a copy and modifying it, the original `state` is being altered when the OP doesn't want that.

Comment: It's fine to make a copy of state and mess with it for non-React purposes, but it's unclear whether `a` `b` and `c` are primitive values or not and, if not, whether `runSimulationWithState` mutates them. If they're primitive and/or `runSimulationWithState` isn't mutating nested structures, there should be no problem (but it's still a design smell). I guess a [mcve] would be needed to really comment further, it's a lot of speculation here.

Comment: @FoundingBox Exactly! How it worked was -> state was a chess board, I would make a move on the copy of the board, make a move on the copied board, and check all possible correct moves. But when I made a move on the copy of the board the actual state would change also. It was very weird... board was an array of arrays and the values were either empty strings or strings representing pieces.

Comment: It's possible that the way you're copying the state may be copying by reference rather than creating a new copy. To echo what @ggorlen said can you add a small portion of what your state actually looks like to your post?

Comment: That's probably the problem, then: `[...arr]` does not deeply copy an array, the inner arrays are still references, so you need to copy all of the nested structures. You probably want `state.map(e => e.slice())` if it's a 2d array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're copying a multidimensional array it's possible that you're copying the state by reference. So when you modify the copy, you'd be modifying the original state as well. [This guide](https://dev.to/samanthaming/how-to-deep-clone-an-array-in-javascript-3cig) does a good job of outlining why arrays are copied by reference.

In this case, since the arrays only contain strings (which are supported by JSON) the following approach should work in creating a true copy.

```
const handleClick = () => {
   var state_copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state));
   state_copy[2] = d;
   runSimulationWithState(state_copy);
}
```